# which neural network topology to learn correlations between time series?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, correlation

I have two (or more in principle) 1xN time series, and I would like to train a NN to predict the next value of both. I can arrange them as a 2xN matrix and feed a window from this matrix as input to the NN, but I'm not sure how to structure the NN itself.

I have made a NN with convolutions that can do a pretty decent job with a single series, but I'd like to exploit cross-series correlations. What topology works to let the NN notice correlations between the time series?

Comment: CNNs handle 2D out of the box. In fact that is their biggest use case (images). Why do you think you have to use something fancier?

Comment: What is the relationship between the two time series? If there is no relation, what is the reason for combining them as input?

Answer (score 2):

It depends a little on what kind of correlations you're looking for. Are you expecting a correlation that is present at each time step/window, or a different level of correlation per time step/window? Are you doing a classification or a regression task? Sometimes predicting the next value involves classification, but I'll assume you're looking for regression for now.

As a starting point, try feeding each of those sequences separately as input to a recurrent neural network (start with a basic LSTM and pare it down if it's overkill). I like your suggestion of overlapping windows.

For example (pseudocode-ish):

```
series_1 = 1, 2, 3, ..., 100

series_2 = 5, 6, 7, ..., 200

input_1 = Input(series_1,       window_size)

input_2 = Input(series_2, window_size)

layer_1 = LSTM(input_1, input_2)

final_layer = fully_connected(layer_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check an **LSTM-RNN** or **GRU-RNN** implementation; the second one is easier to understand and less computationally expensive.

A valuable example is:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly provide correlation as an nn input, as calculated in [Local Correlation Tracking in Time Series](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6cc7/7f1d1860a8e3766f2a9ece65f90c31632582.pdf), with code available via [Vlad's Blog](http://dovgalecs.com/blog/matlab-local-correlation-tracking-in-time-series/).

I have also read a paper ( unfortunately I can't remember its title or names of authors for a google search ) where a prediction of future correlation is an explicit nn target as part of a multivariate target nn target. The authors claimed inclusion of correlation as a target improved the accuracy on the non-correlation part of the multivariate target.